# Installing CoTurn 4.5.0.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 TLS not working

Tags: ubuntu, webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I am trying to install CoTurn 4.5.0.6 on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I can't use `sudo apt-get install coturn` since it installs version 4.5.0.3. Also I can't install Ubuntu 17.10 since I need long term support (TLS).

I create a droplet on Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. Then I downloaded CoTurn:

```
wget https://github.com/coturn/coturn/archive/4.5.0.6.tar.gz
```

I unpack it:

```
tar xvfz 4.5.0.6.tar.gz
```

Go inside the folder:

```
cd coturn-4.5.0.6
```

Install Libraries & Utilities needed:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libhiredis-dev
```

The last one gives an error: `E: Unable to locate package libhiredis-dev`.

After that running:

```
./configure
```

I get error messages:

```
ginstall: not found
install is /usr/bin/install
pkill is /usr/bin/pkill
sqlite3 is /usr/bin/sqlite3
Use TMP dir /var/tmp
Compiler: unknown
ERROR: cannot use compiler unknown properly
```

Can someone give me a step by step instructions to install CoTurn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you ran into some of the same stuff I did. I am going to lunch, but will give a better answer later. For now, here's an exact copy from my terminal commands. You can see how I had to install dependencies and then retry.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev libevent-dev libhiredis-dev make –y
mkdir /coturn
cd coturn
wget http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v4.5.0.6/turnserver-4.5.0.6.tar.gz
tar -zxvf turnserver-4.5.0.6.tar.gz
cd turnserver-4.5.0.6
./configure
apt-get install libssl-dev
install libsqlite3
apt-get install libsqlite3
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
apt-get install libevent-dev
apt-get install libpq-dev
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
apt-get install libhiredis-dev
./configure
apt-get install coturn4.5.0.6
Compiler: unknown
apt-get install gdebi-core
gdebi coturn*.deb
./configure
apt-get install ginstall
make install
CC=g** ./configure
apt-get install build-essential
cd ..
tar -zxvf turnserver-4.5.0.6.tar.gz
cd turnserver-4.5.0.6
./configure
Make install
apt-get --purge remove coturn
```

I was using root. If you are not, you'll probably have to sudo before a lot of these.
I think there is another SO question with some of these steps, but it wasn't step by step either, I had to read several sources and then still experiment some.

I made a file like this in `/etc/systemd/system/turnserver.service` Whatever you name the file will be the name of the service. `sudo systemctl enable turnserver`

```
[Unit]
Description=Turnserver Service

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
TimeoutSec=0
Restart=on-failure
#RestartPreventExitStatus=1
#PrivateTmp=false
PIDFile=/var/run/turnserver_service.pid
ExecStart=/coturn/turnserver-4.5.0.6/bin/turnserver
KillMode=process

StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: So probably do everything in my answer that follows the line that says "Compiler: unknown"

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only thing that was missing: `apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: How does your `/etc/systemd/system/coturn.service` look like? Mine doesn't work anymore. Can't find `/usr/bin/turnserver`. In what folder does `turnserver` gets installed?

Comment: I installed mine in a different folder than the package manager because I didn't delete the old one until I had the new version. I made the directory `coturn` in the root directory; however, it can be where ever yous started the download of the source files. Perhaps in your home folder. I'll add my service file, which is basic. Still haven't researched everything in your other one.

Comment: This helped me to upgrade to `4.5.1.1`